# Refer to a date in another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I am trying to refer to a date in another worksheet, but when the date is blank I end up with a bunch of 1900 dates.

So I tried using this formula : =IF('Titulaires'!D3="","",'Titulaires'!D3). but it doesn,t work and I don't see why
Since the IF statement work like : condition, true action, false action. i thought it would of worked

[image]

Comment: `=IF('Titulaires'!D3="","",'Titulaires'!D3)`  You forgot the sheet on the check

Comment: It still doesnt work tho

Comment: @NicolasForget can you show us how it doesn't work you? That is a working solution provided by Scott Sir

Comment: You can refer to the image i've added now in the post

Comment: @NicolasForget formula should work as I said, you need to use semi colon in place of commas, `=IF('Titulaires'!D3="";"";'Titulaires'!D3)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya now it lets me put it but it results in "#NAME?

Comment: What is your excel language version ? Are you using Excel in English ?

Comment: You might be using Excel in French, hence `IF()` should be `SI()` then. `=SI('Titulaires'!D3="";"";'Titulaires'!D3)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya lmao you're right thats why... i hate french excel now. TYSM tho